# How does Doppler effect differ between EM -waves in Electrodynamics and Sound -waves?

Tags: electromagnetism, specific-reference, doppler-effect

I have an electrodynamics -course that contains doupler -effect but unfortunately with little explanations. Is it the same thing as the classical doppler effect for example with sound, more [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doppler_effect), or do I need to take into account something such as Quantum-theoretical -corrections or something else?

*Griffiths in the "Introduction to Electrodynamics" has something on the page 463, investigating -- other reading?*

Comment: Perhaps related [here](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/29551/quantum-explanation-of-doppler-effect).

Answer (score 3):

There is an important difference.

With sound waves, it makes a difference whether the source or the receiver is moving, because what *really* matters is their speed relative to the medium (air in this case).

With EM waves, on the other hand, it only matters what the relative speed between emitter and receiver is, i.e. it doesn't matter whether the source is moving towards the receiver or the receiver towards the source, because EM waves don't really have a medium to travel in.