# Generator of Velocity Transformations - Galilean Transformations

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, galilean-relativity

Under a Galilean transformation, the coordinates and momenta of any system transform as:
$$ t \rightarrow t',\\ \vec r\:' = \vec r + \vec vt,\\ \vec p\:' = \vec p + m\vec v  $$ 
where $\vec v$ is velocity of frame moving w.r.t it. Now, what will be unitary transformation that can that will carry out this transformation. Let us say the total momentum of the system is $\vec P$ and its mass $M$ and its position $X$.
I know how to write a single coordinate translation, but am not able to put all these together.

**An Attempt** : The transformation should contain :

$ \bf e^{i \vec p.\vec x} $ for translations and $ \bf e^{iHt}$ for time translations, **but what about generators of Velocity transformations ?**

Comment: I think this question answers mine, almost : http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/56024/.

Comment: Although, I would be interested understanding how generators of Galilean boosts can be found.

Answer (score 2):

Time translations are generated by $H$, as expected. The generator for Gallilean boosts $\vec{K}$ is related to the CM operator $\vec{R}=1/M\sum_i m_i\vec{x}_i$, 
$\vec{K}=M\vec{R}$. See  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schr%C3%B6dinger_group for some references.