# Galilean transformation of Schrodinger equation and momentum operator

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, schroedinger-equation, inertial-frames, galilean-relativity

Let
$$
\left.\begin{aligned}
t'&=t\\x'&=x-vt
\end{aligned}\right\} \quad \Longrightarrow\quad \dot{x}'=\dot{x}-v
$$
and therefore $p'=p-mv$.

If $p'=-i\hbar\nabla' $, then $\nabla'=\nabla-iv/\hbar$. Shouldn't  the partial derivatives $$\frac{\partial}{\partial x'}=\frac{\partial x}{\partial x'} \frac{\partial}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial t}{\partial x'} \frac{\partial}{\partial t}=\frac{\partial}{\partial x}-\frac{1}{v}\frac{\partial}{\partial t}$$
why $\nabla'=\nabla$?

If the Schrodinger equation exhibits Galilean invariance, how to prove the new wave function $\psi'(x',t')$ only times a factor ($\psi'(x',t')=a(x,t)\psi(x,t))$?

Comment: your computation is wrong: $\partial t/\partial x'=0$$

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/56024/2451 and links therein.